# How to close a menu by clicking outside the area of the open button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A menu opens when a specific button is clicked `#btn`.

I would like to have the menu close, by also clicking outside the button.

Here is the FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/rkapkoLu/

Is this possible?

Here is the javascript:

```
(function() {
  var btn       = $('#btn');
  menu      = $('nav ul');
  menuHeight    = menu.height();

  $(btn).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('body *:not('#btn')').click(function(){})`

Comment: Assign event listener to document that checks if event target is _not_ the menu close said menu, I guess…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
    $('html').click(function() {
menu.slideUp();
});

$('.nav-wrapper').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: In addition to my current code or instead of my current code?

Comment: Add this to your code
Do you want something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/rkapkoLu/2/ ??

Answer (score 2):

You literally want to have action after clicking on something that is not `#btn` button.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('body *').not('#btn').click(function(){
     e.preventDefault();
     menu.slideToggle();
  })
});
```

Do not forget to unattach the event afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set listener on body

```
        $(".image").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });
```

Comment: I tried this, but it closed the menu right after again.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rkapkoLu/1/

Comment: Yeah sorry, body means whole document. you need to identify the element which respond to click. I have updated the answer.

Comment: by doing this it looks like I am also able to open the menu by clicking the '.image' class

Comment: Yeah that is the problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

use onblur event. It is the opposite of onfocus and is fired when the element loses the focus

```
onblur
```

Answer (score -2):

I would HIGHLY recommend jQuery outsideevents http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

`$(btn).bind("clickoutside", function(event){
// Code to hide your menu.
});`

It does all the work of finding everything that's "not the button" for you.

I should also mention it does a lot more than clickoutside, like you could check if they focusoutside too so if they use tab shortcuts to navigate the page the menu still closes, etc.

Comment: The triumph of form over content. You can do the same (look at the source code) without plugin.

Comment: Nope, nope, nope, nope

Comment: Of course you can do the same without the plugin. A plugin is merely code, so anything any plugin does can be done without a plugin. However, my point is you can make your application much more robust much more easily. For example, closing a menu simply when someone clicks outside does not work very nicely with screen readers. You should handle tabbing, focus, etc. And an answer like "Nope, nope, nope, nope" doesn't add value to the discussion. How about providing reasons why it's such a bad idea since I've given reasons why it is a better idea than the other proposals.